# PHP namespace error

Tags: 7

I'm using libraries, not using composer, and it's on Drupal 7. I installed and enabled [xautoload](https://www.drupal.org/project/xautoload) so that I can use classes from a library that has namespacing. I think I got the xautoload function of this working correctly, because it is not throwing errors anymore when I have a `use SSRS\SSRSReport;` statement at the top of my module file referencing the library's classes.

The problem is that I still seem to have some namespacing fatal error in a libary's class file. This is my `hook_libraries_info()`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_libraries_info().
 *
 * For defining external libraries.
 */
function ssrs_libraries_info() {
  $libraries['ssrs-sdk'] = array(
    'name' => 'SSRS SDK for PHP',
    'vendor url' => 'https://github.com/EmergencyReporting/ssrsreport',
    'download url' => 'https://github.com/EmergencyReporting/ssrsreport',
    'version callback' => 'ssrs_get_version',
    'files' => array(
      'php' => array('library/SSRS/SSRSReport.php'),
    ),
    'xautoload' => function($adapter) {
      // Register a namespace with PSR-0 root in <library dir>/library/
      // Note: $adapter already knows the <library dir>.
      $adapter->add('SSRS', 'library');
    },
  );
  return $libraries;
}
```

Anyways, the error I get is this:

```
Fatal error: Interface 'SSRS\Interfaces\ISSRSBaseType' not found in /sites/all/libraries/ssrs-sdk/library/SSRS/SSRSType/ExecutionInfo2.php on line 34
```

And the line the error in ExecutionInfo2.php is on the line starting `class ExecutionInfo2 ...`:

```
namespace SSRS\SSRSType;
use SSRS\Interfaces\ISSRSBaseType;

/**
 *
 * class ExecutionInfo2
 */
class ExecutionInfo2 extends SSRSBaseType implements ISSRSBaseType {
```

So I don't get errors from the namespaces' `use` statements, but the interface class doesn't appear to actually be loaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that despite not using composer, I can give the library's provided `composer.json` file to xautoload, and it will get the information it needs.

```
$adapter->composerJson('composer.json');
```

I also found in the composer.json file the information I would have needed to use `$adapter->addPsr4`, with each individual namespace needing to be added separately:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "SSRS\\": "library/SSRS/",
        "SSRS\\Common\\": "library/SSRS/Common/",
        "SSRS\\Factory\\": "library/SSRS/Factory/",
        "SSRS\\Interfaces\\": "library/SSRS/Interface/",
        "SSRS\\RenderType\\": "library/SSRS/RenderType/",
        "SSRS\\SSRSType\\": "library/SSRS/SSRSType/",
        "SSRS\\TestConnection\\": "library/SSRS/TestConnection/"
    }
}
```